# Wrong letters when I'm typing with Macbook Pro

Tags: mac, keyboard, macos

My Mac is typing that symbols 
œ∑´®†¥¨ˆøπ
 when I'm pressing buttons qwertyuiop

I am using a MacBook Pro 9,2 (2010) running El Capitan (10.11.3) with a Japanese keyboard and my language set to English.

When I'm using a USB Keyboard I don't have this problem

Comment: MacBook Pro Model?  macOS version?  Is the keyboard an US English keyboard?

Comment: MacBook Pro9,2.  2010, 10.11.3 OS X

Comment: It's Japanese  .

Answer (score 10):

This unicode combination can be produced when holding down the alt/option key on your Mac's keyboard. If you google this issue, there is a [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4815782?tstart=0) from 2013/14 describing a solution to this issue.

Here are the summarised steps to revert they keyboard back to its intended use:

1. Open system preferences
2. Select accessibility
3. Select keyboard
4. Enable sticky keys
5. Press option twice quickly to enable sticky and once more to turn it off (option key must be enabled if you previously disabled it in modifier key controls)
6. Problem solved! - Turn sticky keys off again

I can verify that these steps are still valid for macOS High Sierra but do let me know how you get on.

Comment: I wonder why sticky keys would not have the same effect with a usb keyboard.

Comment: It didn't worked out. I have a Japanese Mac. I think the problem is with unicode or something like that.

Comment: @Tom Gewecke, Sticky Keys has the same effect on a USB attached keyboard, or Bluetooth attached keyboard to the MacBook Pro as the internal keyboard of the MacBook Pro as long as it has been activated on that particular keyboard. In other words, with Sticky Keys enabled, one must press the defined modifier key on the target keyboard to activate Sticky Keys on that keyboard. Activating/Deactivating Sticky Keys on one keyboard does not affect the activation state on the other keyboard(s).

Comment: @123  Unicode is irrelevant here.  The machine just thinks your option key is always down for some reason.

Comment: sticky keys fix seems to have worked for me, thanks very much!

Comment: Confirmed on Catalina, had this issue with an external keyboard after an update; sticky keys on then off fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the sticky keys fix does not work, then the fact that an external keyboard works ok most likely indicates that the internal one is damaged.

Answer (score 2):

Though this [solution](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/94749/Keyboard+is+typing+the+wrong+character) looks weird, but it works:

Run your fingers over all the keys. I too faced the same error because some key was stuck, rubbing fingers over all the keys helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. The **Logitech Gaming Software** application was causing the problem. I quit the application and the problem stopped. (The Logitech application is sporadically unstable)

Even if you aren't running the **Logitech Gaming Software**, try quitting any applications (especially those running in the background) that could be related to keyboard inputs and outputs, e.g. mouse software, text shortcuts, macros, abbreviation expanders, etc.

Comment: I assume the Logitech software would have had the same effect on an external keyboard,  Do you know if that is correct?